# Displaying Selected Values in Drop-Down List With Multple = On

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display **ALL** selected values in a drop down list.  The code shown below works to display only the first value however I'm struggling on understanding how to get it to display **each** value that is selected.

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementsByName("Car").item(0).value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>
<select name="Car" multiple="on" size="5" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="Audi">Audi
<option value="BMW">BMW
<option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
<option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>
<br>
The car is:
<p id="demo"></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2gq824q2/12/

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier but I would like to use NAME (not ID) to perform this task.  The HTML for the select drop-down options is being generated by a "program" that includes NAME (not ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use jQuery when you can?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = $('#car').val()
    $('#demo').html("You selected: " + x.join(", "))
}
$('#car').change(function() {
  myFunction();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="car" name="Car" multiple="on" size="5">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>
<br>
The car is:
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using an ID and using NAME?

Comment: You can use `$('select[name=Car]')`, but why not use ID?

Comment: Thank you.  That works.  I'm using another program that generates the HTML to create the dropdown and the program generated code doesn't include an ID (only a NAME).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/2gq824q2/15/

```js
function myFunction() {
    var sSelected = '';
    [].forEach.call(  document.querySelectorAll('#Car :checked')  , function(elm){
        if(sSelected !== '') sSelected += ', ';
      sSelected += elm.value;
  })
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + sSelected;
}
```

```html
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="Car" multiple="on" size="5" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>
<br>
The car is:
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I updated the function, and note the select now has an ID.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using an ID (using only NAME)?