# Display Selected Values in Drop Down on Page Load (Multiple=on)

Tags: jquery

This is a follow-up to my earlier question: [Displaying Selected Values in Drop-Down List With Multple = On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757331/displaying-selected-values-in-drop-down-list-with-multple-on/38757425#38757425)

The help provided allowed me to capture the selected values when they were modified however I could not figure out how to capture the initial values (selected) when the page first loaded.

```
   function myFunction() {
       var x = $('select[name=Car]').val()
       $('#demo').html("You selected: " + x.join(", "))
   }
   $('select[name=Car]').change(function() {
     myFunction();
   });
   $('select[name=Car]').load(function() {
     myFunction();
   });

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select name="Car" multiple="on" size="5">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW" selected>BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo" selected>Volvo
</select>
<br>
The car is:
<p id="demo"></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2gq824q2/18/

I would like the initial value(s), in this case BMW and Mercedes to be shown when the page is loaded and then be changed if alternate selections are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use a `.load` - just simply call `myFunction` on page load (after the page has been loaded):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2gq824q2/19/

`.load` is for loading another page within your page.

Comment: Is it possible to return the 'text' field for the option instead of the value of the option?  For example I've modified  https://jsfiddle.net/2gq824q2/20/ to have different names for the value and "text".

Comment: @Dogsled -- Yeah sure - get the `selectedIndex` and go from there:

Comment: I've searched for selectedIndex and it leads me to believe that var x = $("select[name=Car] option:selected").text() should work but unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up deviating a bit from the original code and just wanted to contribute back.

```
<script>
function showDropDownValues() {
var str = "";
$( "select[name=Car] option:selected" ).each(function() {
    str += $( this ).text() + ", ";
    });
$('#demo').html("You selected: " + str);  
};

$( "select[name=Car]" ).change(function() {
showDropDownValues();
});

showDropDownValues();
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select name="Car" multiple="on" size="5">
<option value="Audi">Audi Car</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW Car</option>
<option value="Mercedes" selected>Mercedes Car</option>
<option value="Volvo">Volvo Car</option>
</select>


The car is:
<p id="demo"></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2gq824q2/25/